# ValueError: The arguments array must contain 2 items, 1 given appears after running composer update (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, composer-php

I've tried to run `composer update` for my laravel project. But after that, when I tried to save some changes for an entry in my database, I get the following error:

```
The arguments array must contain 2 items, 1 given
```

[Here is a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxEvH.png)

The laravel.log file give this information:

```
local.ERROR: The arguments array must contain 2 items, 1 given {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ValueError(code: 0): The arguments array must contain 2 items, 1 given at /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php:695)
#0 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php(695): vsprintf()
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator->Illuminate\\Validation\\{closure}()
#2 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php(694): array_map()
#3 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php(588): Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator->replaceAsterisksInParameters()
#4 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php(422): Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator->validateAttribute()
#5 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php(453): Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator->passes()
#6 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait.php(31): Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator->fails()
#7 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/FormRequestServiceProvider.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\FormRequest->validateResolved()
#8 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1279): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\FormRequestServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\{closure}()
#9 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1244): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->fireCallbackArray()
#10 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1229): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->fireAfterResolvingCallbacks()
#11 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(790): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->fireResolvingCallbacks()
#12 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(856): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#13 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(706): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#14 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#15 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php(85): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#16 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php(50): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->transformDependency()
#17 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->resolveMethodDependencies()
#18 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(60): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->resolveClassMethodDependencies()
#19 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(40): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->resolveParameters()
#20 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(260): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()
#21 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(205): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#22 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(798): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#23 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()
#24 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#25 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle()
#26 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(44): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#27 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle()
#28 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#29 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
#30 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#31 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()
#32 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#33 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest()
#34 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle()
#35 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#36 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
#37 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#38 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle()
#39 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#40 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(799): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#41 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(776): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#42 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(740): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#43 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(729): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#44 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(190): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#45 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#46 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/DisableBrowserCache.php(19): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#47 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Livewire\\DisableBrowserCache->handle()
#48 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#49 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#50 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle()
#51 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#52 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#53 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle()
#54 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#55 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#56 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#57 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#58 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#59 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors->handle()
#60 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#61 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle()
#62 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/itsgoingd/clockwork/Clockwork/Support/Laravel/ClockworkMiddleware.php(24): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#63 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Clockwork\\Support\\Laravel\\ClockworkMiddleware->handle()
#64 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#65 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#66 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(134): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#67 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#68 /home/lasse/Documents/ml_ns/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/resources/server.php(16): require_once('...')
#69 {main}
```

Before running composer update, the function worked perfectly fine. I've had this error before and it could be easily fixed by rollback composer.lock to the earlier version, but this isn't the case now. I've tried to rollback the changes of composer update, but the error is still there. I've tried the following things, but it didn't work:

- rollback `composer.lock` to an earlier state where the error wasn't there
- deleted all `vendor` files and running `composer install` with the old `composer.lock` file
- running `php artisan view:clear`

I am using PHP 8.1.18 and Laravel 9.52.5. If somebody know what I did wrong when trying to revert the changes or how to fix the error, I would be really happy!

Comment: "But after that" - what does that mean? Did Composer run successfully? If yes, are you sure this problem is related to Composer itself? Also, why not share more details about the packages you use, and the code that triggers this problem? What has changed when running `composer update`?